# How to return database error from restful service?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, rest

I am writing both server and client side. If request is successful or have error like HTTP 404, 400, 405 etc... I can handle it without any problem. However, I dont know what is the best way to handle errors from database side. Like;

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UserInfo_image_id_key"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (image_id)=(123123) already exists.
```

If there is update on db I can check it like;

```
int result = ps.executeUpdate();                        
            if (result > 0) {
                System.out.println("Successfully updated");
                return true;                        
            } else {
                System.out.println("DB not updated!");
                return false;
            }
```

Could you please help me how I can handle such error case on `else loop`.

Comment: You, as the programmer,  should make sure that the keys inserted in the database are unique. It is a bad practice to let users send/create incorrect keys, so this primarily seems to be a design issue.

Comment: @dsp_user since it is server client project. How client side should know about database if there is no service ?

Comment: No, I would argue that the server side code should create unique keys. You can use a sequence in the database or an autoincremented field/column (the easiest solution). That said, sometimes you may still want to send a user message back to the client and for this you may indeed create a simple Java class (a POJO) and return a POJO object to the client.

Comment: @dsp_user yes, so the question is how I will create this POJO class in best way to handle such error cases

Comment: I'll write a simple example and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return a user message back to the client, you First need to create a simple Java class (POJO) that will contain the message.

Your POJO might look like

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

 @XmlRootElement(name = "userMsg")
 public class UserMessage implements Serializable {

  public  enum UserCodes { SUCCESS, DATA_ALREADY_EXIST, DATA_WRONG_FORMAT };

 private enum userCode ;
 private String userMsg ;

 public UserMessage(){
 userCode = UserCodes.SUCCESS; //DEFAULT
 userMsg =  "Request successful";
 }

 public UserCodes getUserCode(){
return userCode;
}
public void setUserCode(UserCodes code){
 userCode = code;
}
public String getUserMsg(){
return userMsg;
}
 public void setUserMsg(String msg){
 userMsg = msg;
 }
 }
```

Your server side code (Jersey in my case)

```
  @GET
  @Path("/insertRecord") 
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
  public UserMessage someInsertMethod(@QueryParam("id") int id){
  UserMessage uMsg = new UserMessage();
  try{
//try insert here

 }catch(SqlException sqle){

  switch (sqle.getErrorCode()){
  case num1:  //replace num1 with the actual error code
    uMsg.setUserCode(UserMessage.UserCodes.DATA_ALREADY_EXIST);
    uMsg.setUserMsg(" Key already exists");
    break;
  case num2:
  uMsg.setUserCode(UserMessage.UserCodes.DATA_WRONG_FORMAT);
    uMsg.setUserMsg(" Data wrong format");
    break;
  }
  }
return uMsg;
 }
```

Note that Jersey is converting a UserMessage into an XML (serialization). This could of course, be JSON.

The client code (again Jersey assumed)

```
           ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

            WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8088/JerseyRest").build());   

            try{
                UserMessage msg =(UserMessage) target.path("rest").path("insertRecord").request()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(UserMessage.class);

               if(msg.getUserCode() != UserMessage.UserCodes.SUCCESS)
                   System.out.println("Msg: " + msg.getUserMsg());


            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                return;
            }
```

In your client code just check that msg.getUserCode() != UserMessage.UserCodes.SUCCESS and then display the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The client should **not** know the server has a problem with some backend. So whether it's the database which causes the issue, should only be visible in the log of your rest-api.
You could also return HTTP 200 (OK) when the update succeeds, a HTTP 201 when a new record is created, and a HTTP 409 (conflict) when you get a duplicate key violation or st like that.

Dealing with your database issue, is just coding, so I guess that's not your question ;-)

Comment: This. The server should blackbox the exact error from client, unless it was caused by the client's request (but then, that shouldn't propagate till the DB/DAO layer without validation).

Comment: Sorry if I have wrong with my question. I need return error string to client side which is `"image_id is already exists"`

Comment: You can add a message as a body in your returnvalue. I don't know if you use any framework, e.g. Jersey (I hope you do), then you can just add: `return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity("image_id already exists").build();`

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to make one error handling pojo class at server side like below and returns its object with json conversion in catch block with proper error message , on client side you can access its attribute in success or then block of your ajax or rest call

```
public class CustomError {

    public CustomError (int errorCode, String errorMessage) {

        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;

    }

    public CustomError (String errorMessage) {

        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;

    }
    public CustomError () {


    }

    private String errorMessage;

    private int errorCode;

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }


}

try{

//db code
}Catch(Exception e){

CustomError customError = new CustomError (errorCode,e.getMessage());
//covert customError   to json
return jsonString;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a DB error like that the executeUpdate will throw a [SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html).

There's several ways to handle that :

- the simpliest one is to handle with a try catch block.
- A more advanced one would to use Interceptor (if j2ee) or AoP (if Spring) to handle exception in a more board way